# The project 'MyProject.csproj' could not be opened. The project output type is not supported

Tags: visual-studio, expression-blend, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to open a project in Blend for VS 2012 in win7. The only thing changed between then(when it worked) and now(when it doesn't) was an update for visual studio.

Any ideas on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blend for Visual Studio 2012 RC only supports Windows 8 Metro style projects, which can only be built on Windows 8.  WPF and Silverlight are not supported.